# Must I define both the forward declaration and the interface of a class in the same section?

Tags: delphi

I have a class that I want to keep private, because I only use it in the implementation section.
However it is used by a class that is declared public in the interface section.

Is there a way to do something like this:

```
unit x;

interface

  type
    TPrivate = class;  //forward declaration

    TPublic = class(TSomething)
    private
      FPrivate: TPrivate;
      procedure DoStuffWithFPrivate;
    public
      //...
    end;

 implementation

 type
   TPrivate = class(TObject)
     procedure Test;
   end;
```

Obviously the above code gives an error:

> [dcc32 Error] UnitX.pas(27): E2086 Type 'TPrivate' is not yet completely defined

I don't want to resort to cheap tricks like:

```
FPrivate = TObject
....
procedure TPublic.DoStuffWithFPrivate;
begin
  TPrivate(FPrivate).Test;
```

Is there a way to do what I want without having to spill `TPrivate`'s internal details in the interface?

I know it's possible to declare TPrivate as a `strict private` sub type of TPublic, however I don't like the pollution of the interface section this gives.
Is there a way to keep `TPrivate` out the of `interface` section (as much as possible) whilst maintaining type safety?

Comment: You've already found the best options

Comment: It is not only the same section. The actual declaration has to be done inside the scope of the same `type` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as `TPrivate` is not used anywhere in the interface of `TPublic` besides the field declaration (f.i. as a methods parameter type) you can use a local `class helper` to achieve this.

Note: `FPrivate` is not a good name for that field!

```
interface

type
  THiddenActual = class
  end;

  TPublic = class
  private
    FActual: THiddenActual;
    procedure DoStuffWithFPrivate;
  public
  end;

implementation

type
  TActual = class(THiddenActual)
  public
    procedure Foo;
  end;

type
  TPublicHelper = class helper for TPublic
  private
    function GetActual: TActual;
    procedure SetActual(const Value: TActual);
  public
    property Actual: TActual read GetActual write SetActual;
  end;

procedure TActual.Foo;
begin
end;

function TPublicHelper.GetActual: TActual;
begin
  Result := FActual as TActual;
end;

procedure TPublicHelper.SetActual(const Value: TActual);
begin
  FActual := Value;
end;

procedure TPublic.DoStuffWithFPrivate;
begin
  Actual.Foo;
end;
```

OK, it is merely a little variance of that cheap trick, but what are the alternatives? You have to take what is available, don't you?

Comment: +100 What a great solution. Now I can keep my interface clean! Thanx. It does create problems relating to the limitations inherent in class helpers, but I'll take what I can get. **I wish emba would upgrade class helpers to be first class citizens**.

Comment: The downsides of this far outweigh any benefits

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, yes the testing that I'm doing does indicate this... properties in class helpers don't work, and lots more. Until helpers are implemented to their full potential it will not work except in a few very limited cases.

Comment: Looks like you can declare `FActual` field in the helper, then you don't need `THiddenActual` type at all.

Comment: @user246408, you can't declare fields in a helper. Which is a major downside of helpers.

Comment: If you need a method that uses `TPrivate` in its signature, you can just declare the method in the class helper.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what exactly your definition of "pollution" is as regards the interface section, but if it's just a matter of keeping it from drowning your `TPublic` class definition with noise then one option might be simply inheritance :

```
TBasePublic = class(TSomething)
  private
    type
      TPrivate = class
        // ...
        // ... keep TPrivate definition separate
      end;
end;

TPublic = class(TBasePublic)
  private
    FPrivate : TPrivate;
end;
```

This would even allow you to define `TPrivate` in a completely different unit if segregation is your goal.

Comment: That's the option discussed in the question as leaving pollution

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I understood that option to be nesting it in the main class itself - inheritance here at least provides the option to separate the definitions (ie: there is no 'pollution' of the `TPublic` class, at least).  Like I said, I don't really understand what OP's notion of "pollution" is, but this is one solution based on a guess of what, exactly, the objection is...  A forward declaration would let this move to the bottom of the interface section.  Seems bizarre to me to care too much about whether `interface` gets written above this definition or below it.

Comment: It's just the sub type approach described in the Q. Would need to be protected to put in a different unit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, that's true, and yes, it is.  I still don't think that makes it an invalid suggestion.  The question is (almost) entirely one of aesthetics and sometimes an obvious solution escapes us.

Comment: It's a reasonable answer to the question. Personally I'd just declare the type in the interface section and be done with it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Agreed, likewise.

Comment: As I see it, simplicity is the key driver here. Any of the options suggested make the code so much more complex and harder to read as to negate any minor benefit. In my view.